# Many Questions for a project

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I am working on a project for work. I have a really hard time understanding the documentation for a software package. I have asked several questions on the tag. They all fit the tag but I have the vast majority of the posts on that tag. I don't want to be leaching or have anyone do my project for me. Is there a way around this problem? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: No, if you're asking good questions and people are able to answer them then you're using the site well :-).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards But are they good questions, that's really the question here.

Comment: I'm not so sure @Servy; it seemed to me that the question was more whether asking others to do your project by proxy or having all the questions in any one tag was a problem. _My (:-)) answer is that it's not, assuming the questions are good. If they're not, that is, of course, a different matter...

Comment: @Servy It really is the all one tag problem. There are less than 100 questions on this tag but it is the right tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each of your questions needs to be a well-researched, good question in its own right.  The context isn't particularly important, and by itself, there's nothing wrong with one user dominating the questions in one category.

However, should you be asking many questions on the topic, it might imply you're not generalizing or learning from previous answers.  When one question is answered, not only should you learn the answer, but also a new way of solving the problem. E.g., if someone answered by reading the source code and you hadn't, you should try reading the source code yourself before posting your next question.

But it's of course possible you're just in a relatively obscure or difficult area of software development (e.g. working on a poorly documented library with a small community of users), and there are many questions that do need to be asked.  I would strive to become the expert yourself, even self-answering questions for the benefit of future users.

Bottom line:  If you're getting good feedback (in the form of upvotes and answers, largely), it's okay to keep asking as you are.  But try to get better at answering your own questions anyway.